# Программа для приложения

Tags: c#

Есть приложение(silverlight). Хочу реализовать свою! программу... которая по нажатию на "button" автоматически заполняла окна в приложении(silverlight).
Как мне обратиться к приложению ? открыть его и записать данные в поля

Answer (score 1):

В общем случае никак, приложение должно сотрудничать для того, чтобы изменения, которые вы сделали, были им подхвачены.

В качестве хака можно попробовать [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Если в браузере, то можно попробовать кондовый process.start("Explorer.exe или Chrome и т.д." + параметры запуска). В параметрах запуска можно указать ссылку на файл с данными для формы или для чего там.